# Overflow-x not working in tablet and mobile devices

Tags: css

I have this website swagatobhatta.info

In iPhone, one can see overflow-x happening.. I gave overflow-x hidden. That did not solve the issue.

I even tried the following

```
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position:relative;
```

It didn't fix. Any help please? Not sure what is causing this

Comment: Why don't you try to find the element causing the overflow. Use chrome emulation to emulate an iphone.

Comment: Yeep I been trying for last few hours.. Cant seem to figure out where Exactly.. Btw I tried the code in body.. And overflow-x should have technically fixed it. .However it didn.. Seems like many other faces similar issues.. On google search for severl soln.. But none working for me..

Comment: I've had many issues with overflow on mobile devices. There's always that one div that has a fixed width causes it to overflow. Poke around everywhere and try to find it.

Comment: Yes I agree.. It is always a bit of a last min headache.

Comment: Feels like the menu and the buggy search

Comment: Solved.. It was the buggy search bar.. I need to fix that... Thanks @davidxd333 . You may leave your comment as answer.. Because that was my answer.. I was using developer tools in firefox.. However that doesnt do a good job as chrome emulator

Comment: Made into an answer, glad I helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requested as answer by OP:

There's something on the page that has a fixed width causing the overflow. Use browser emulators to inspect your code on mobile platforms to prevent confusion and headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow-x: hidden;` doesn't work on mobile devices when you have `<meta name='viewport'>` tag on your HTML page.

Try removing the viewport and your code will work fine.